# duvida Input type date

Tags: html, angularjs, html5, input

Boa tarde, estou fazendo um formulário, para cadastro e modificação de usuários. Quando tento inserir uma data nos inputs de type="date", não é exibido nenhum tipo de dado na tela. Essas datas que estou utilizando veem todas de um json que já as possui registradas. Aguem sabe algum tipo de solução para isso ?

```
    <div layout="row" flex>
      <md-input-container flex>
        <label>Data de Adesao</label>
        <input type="date" name="adesao" ng-model="userSettings.userForm.adesaoUserForm ">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container flex>
        <label>Data Vencimento</label>
        <input type="date" name="vencimento" ng-model="userSettings.userForm.vencimentoUserForm  " >
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, imagino que o formado da data seja o problema.
O padrão default do input date é "mm/dd/yyyy", se a data informada estiver com outro padrão o valor não será exibido.
Dê uma olha na documentação em: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: no banco de dados as datas estão gravadas nesse formato :
          "2017-02-08T00:00:00.000Z"

Comment: Descupe amigo, te passei o padrão errado, o correto é yyyy-mm-dd. Tente assim: ``<input type="date" name="bday" value="2017-06-12">``