# asp:Textbox type="date" não é preenchido

Tags: c#, asp

Estou criando um formulário em asp onde um `asp:Textbox` deveria carregar a data de validade de um produto, que deveria ser preenchido no page_load() com os dados da banco, e ser livre para alteração, caso necessário

O problema é que, com o `type="date"` eu não consigo preencher o campo no pageload da pagina:

a data que o banco retorna: `{28/02/2020 00:00:00}`

TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox type="date" id="txtValidade" class="TextBoxSaldo" Width="50%" runat="server" />
```

Chamada para preencher o campo:

```
txtValidade.Text = lstValidade[0].DT_VALIDA.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

**O que eu ja tentei:**

Mudar o formato da data:
Nessa outra [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212336/duvida-input-type-date), a resposta aceita diz que o problema é no formato da data, então tentei mudar o formato para

```
lstValidade[0].DT_VALIDA.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

e não rolou.

Definir o CultureInfo:

no CodeBihide tentei definir os formatos para "pt-BR"

```
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
```

se eu alterar o tipo do input para text, funciona, mas eu perco a função do formato de data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O formato do atributo `value=` para o `type=date` deveria ser este:

```html
<input type="date" value="2020-02-05">
```

E não isto:

```html
<input type="date" value="02/05/2020">
```

Veja que o segundo não funciona, aparece `dd/mm/aaaa`, se o navegador estiver em "portugues do Brasil", logo o problema é o `value` que você passou, creio que se ajuste assim:

```
txtValidade.Text = lstValidade[0].DT_VALIDA.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Não pude testar para confirmar porque não tenho asp.net aqui, se falhar me avisa

Comment: Funcionou, só a formatação no `ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")` que, como vc disse, é com `-` e não `/`

Comment: @GabrielOliveira foi erro de digitação meu, a intenção era `-` mesmo, como fiz no primeiro HTML, editei, agora deve estar OK

Answer (score -2):

Eu fiz algo desse tipo e funcionou, só que tava pegando de um objeto DataTable:

DateTime dtCadastro = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["DT_Cadastro"].ToString());
txtdtcadastro.Text = dtCadastro.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd"); //

Answer (score -2):

Mas como foi comentado acima, isso tem haver com a mascara aplicada que no caso foi yyyy-MM-dd.

Também fiz algo parecido para um campo textBox do tipo TextMode="Number" e funcionou de boa.

double precoCusto = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["Preco_Custo"].ToString());
txtprecocusto.Text = precoCusto.ToString("F2",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);